# Using "rather/more" and "than" to compare two things in the same sentence

Tags: word-choice, grammar, word-usage, syntactic-analysis

I wonder which one of the followings is correct or more preferable:

> ... is rather related to X than to Y.
>
> ... is related to X rather than to Y.
>
> ... is more related to X than to Y.
>
> ... is related to X more than to Y.

Any ideas?

Comment: *Rather* doesn't mean *more*; it means *instead of*. So *"I'm a doctor rather than a veterinarian"* doesn't mean the same thing as *"I'm more of a doctor than a veterinarian"*. Which is more correct depends on what you mean.

Comment: @PeterShor I see, thank you! Then, how about the last two sentences, which one is correct?

Comment: I'd say all the sentences are correct except for the first one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

.... is more related to X than to Y

This is perfectly correct. However I prefer not to use "to" before "Y"

Comment: With and without "to", the sentence can have two different meanings.

Comment: @NVZ how, could you please elaborate?

Answer (score 0):

when used with "to" you compare x with the initial subject, and then put emphasis on "than Y" has more in common with the initial subject... without to you compare the initial subject with Y to show which fits X better.